# ASP.NET MVC FormsAuthentication does not expire

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am having a slight issue with my MVC app in that the Authentication cookie set by

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(usr.UserID, true);
```

Appears to never expire despite the timeout being set to 60 seconds in the web.config.

If I login, then wait for a few mins (or even overnight) then go back to the site, I enter the site as if I am fully logged in still......

How do I set it to log me out automatically after a few mins?

Comment: Are you certain you are actually preventing unauthorized users from accessing those pages?

Comment: Yes, I have a [Authorize(Roles="1")] attribute on the action method and it if I call FormsAuthentication.Signout() it then locks me out of that page as expected.

Comment: Have you got any scripts which are polling the application periodically? If so, these will pass your Forms Authentication cookie over which will cause the timeout to reset!

Comment: no, this is not even a live app at the moment. There is nothing polling the site.

Comment: no matter, it appears to be working all of a sudden.... no idea what was causing the issue...